# How to set different global options in knitr RMD file

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I want to exclude a lot of code chunks in my RMD file and had the idea to set the global options with `eval = FALSE` before and then `eval = TRUE` afterwards. But this is not working.

Here a toy example:

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, eval = FALSE)
```
## will not be executed because global option `eval = FALSE`
```{r}
x+y
```

```{r setup II, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(eval = TRUE, echo = TRUE)
```
## Should give `2` in final document, because eval = TRUE
## NOT working as expected
```{r}
1+1
```

## This is working as expected
```{r, eval = TRUE}
1+1
```
````

Here the result:

[image]

Is this a bug or a feature? For my opinion this works counter-intuitive ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not a bug or feature, but expected. You set `eval = FALSE` in the first code chunk, which means the second code chunk will not be evaluated, hence `knitr::opts_chunk$set(eval = TRUE, echo = TRUE)` was not executed at all. Then `eval` is still `FALSE` for the third code chunk.

You need to set `eval = TRUE` on the second code chunk:

````
```{r setup II, include=FALSE, eval=TRUE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(eval = TRUE, echo = TRUE)
```
````

Comment: Is there a way to specify figure dimensions in the global options? I recall doing this previously, but I could not find a quick solution online.